# Chamar função typescript em uma função javascript

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, ionic3

Tenho uma função que quando clica em um botão ela cria um token a partir das informaçōes do usuário.

```
<button ion-button (click)="onTapBuyCart()"></ion-button>
```

Porem quando eu tento chamar a função this.cartPay(); dentro de Mercadopago.createToken(função javascript), acontece esse erro.

[image: this.cartPay is not a function]

```
onTapBuyCart() {
            let form = document.querySelector('#form');
            console.log(form);
            Mercadopago.createToken(form, function (status, response) {
                this.hashCartao = response.id;
                console.log(this.hashCartao + ' HASH');
            this.cartPay();
            });
        }
    }

   public cartPay() {
        console.log(this.hashCartao);
        let loader = this._loaderCtrl.create({
            content: "Validando compra, aguarde um momento"
        });
        loader.present();
        this._cartProvider
            .payCart(
                this.formaPagamentoSelecionada,
                this.nmCartao,
                this.titular,
                this.formaVezes,
                this.hashCartao
            )
            .subscribe(
                (cart: any) => {
                    loader.dismiss();
                    this.navCtrl.setRoot(SucessCartPage, { cart });
                },
                error1 => {
                    var arr = Object.keys(error1.error.errors).map(key => ({
                        type: key,
                        value: error1.error.errors[key]
                    }));
                    this.errorSubscribe = error1.error.errors;
                    this.errorJson = arr;
                    console.log(error1);
                    loader.dismiss();
                    let toast = this._toastCtrl.create({ message: "Ocorreu um erro" , duration:3000 });
                    toast.present();
                }
            );
    }
```

Existe algum maneira de eu chamar essa função typescript dentro de javascript sem dar erro? Muito obrigado por sua atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você usa uma função de callback (essa função que você passa no createToken), dentro de um método, você perde a referência do this, que passa ser a do objeto Mercadopago.

uma forma fácil de resolver isso é guardar o this em uma variável, antes de chamar o Mercadopago.

Ex: let self = this;

Ou também usar arrow function no lugar da função comum